# iPhone etc: how to tell if the device has a camera?

Tags: iphone

Version 3.1.3 if its relevant.

There is this suggestion which may work now, but in the future?

```
NSString *device = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;

if([device isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
#define SOURCETYPE UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera

// does the device have a camera?
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:SOURCETYPE]) {
  // if so, does that camera support video?
  NSArray *mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:SOURCETYPE];
  bool isA3GS = [mediaTypes containsObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie];
}
```

Comment: I'm having a problem trying to use this technique.  Here's the error message I'm getting: `passing argument 1 of 'containsObject:' from incompatible pointer type`  I know it's a CFConstStringRef, but I've never used one of those before... what am I missing here?

Comment: Kyle, it should be: `bool isA3GS = [mediaTypes containsObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]`;

Comment: dont forget to import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>